# Show $\delta_{KL}$ is a Cartesian tensor

Tags: rotations, tensors, fluid-dynamics

By using the definition of kronecker delta $\delta_{KL}$, show that $\delta_{KL}$ is a Cartesian tensor, that is $$\delta ' _{MN}=L_{MK}L_{NL} \delta_{KL}$$ under the rotation $X_K=L_{MK}X' _M$.

I don't really know where to start. What is the result differentiated with respect to? Please help.

Comment: By the way, the "$'$" doesn't mean differentiation, if that's what you were thinking.

Comment: If any of the answeres below were useful to you, then you should [upvote](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) all answers you find useful and [accept](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) the one that was most useful to you. It is a way to show that you have found the answer to your question and it shows your appreciation. Now it seems like you still need help. If answers are not useful to you, then it helps if you say why not. This helps others to help you. For more information [read this](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the inner product in the Cartesian coordinates,
$$
(\mathbf X, \mathbf Y)
=
X_K Y_K
\stackrel{1}{=}
\delta_{KL} X_K Y_L
\stackrel{2}{=}
\delta_{KL} (L_{MK} X'_M) \, (L_{NL} Y'_N)
=
\delta_{KL} L_{MK} \, L_{NL} X'_M Y'_N,
\qquad (1)
$$
the summations over repeated indices are assumed. $\stackrel{1}{=}$ follows from the definition of Kronecker delta; $\stackrel{2}{=}$ from the coordinate tranformation formula provided by the problem.

Now the inner product is a scalar, hence invariant under rotations.
So the above value must be the same as the value computed in the rotated coordinates:
$$
(\mathbf X, \mathbf Y) = X'_N Y'_N = \delta'_{MN} X'_M Y'_N.
\qquad (2)
$$

Equating (1) and (2), we get,
$$
\delta_{KL} L_{MK} \, L_{NL} X'_M Y'_N
=
\delta'_{MN} X'_M Y'_N.
$$
This must hold for *any* vectors $\mathbf X$ and $\mathbf Y$ with arbitrary components $X'_M$ and $Y'_N$, so
$$
\delta'_{MN} = \delta_{KL} L_{MK} \, L_{NL}.
$$